# Python change directory to folder starting by

Tags: python, chdir

Is there a way to change directory in Python to a folder starting by a fixed character, but the rest of the name use a "whatever the rest of the name"?

```
path = os.getenv("HOME")  
os.chdir(path +'/test/Reports/' + year + '/' + mounth + '/')
```

The variable mounth is the numeric current mounth, but the actual mounth folders are the number of the mounth plus the name. So I would like to change directory to a folder that starts with the number of the mount but with something else (as pressing in bash the tab to autofill the rest of the name when it gets a match).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `glob` for wildcard matching, and pass that to `os.chdir`.

```
import os
from glob import glob

dirname = glob('/test/Reports/' + year + '/' + mounth + '*')
os.chdir(dirname[0])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a good way to do it!!